# RSS feed in codeigniter, can't run {php} in <description> tag

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, rss

I have create an rss feed, all things is going to work well, but in this xml code

```
<description><![CDATA[****no php is allowed here****]]></description>
```

here is my view that generate the xml file

```
<?php 
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . "\n";
?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">

    <channel>

    <title><?php echo $feed_name; ?></title>

    <link><?php echo $feed_url; ?></link>
    <description><?php echo $page_description; ?></description>
    <dc:language><?php echo $page_language; ?></dc:language>
    <dc:creator><?php echo $creator_email; ?></dc:creator>

    <dc:rights>Copyright <?php echo gmdate("Y", time()); ?></dc:rights>
    <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://www.codeigniter.com/" />

    <?php foreach($posts as $entry): ?>

        <item>

          <title><?php echo $entry->title_nw; ?></title>
          <link><?php echo site_url('view=entry'.'&amp;'.'id=' . $entry->id_nw); ?></link>
          <guid><?php echo site_url('blog/post/' . $entry->url_title); ?></guid>

          <description><![CDATA[
      <?php character_limiter($entry->text_nw, 200); ?>
      ]]></description>
      <pubDate><?php echo $entry->date_nw;?></pubDate>
        </item>


    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </channel></rss>
```

please scroll down and you can see this code

```
      <description><![CDATA[
  <?php character_limiter($entry->text_nw, 200); ?>
  ]]></description>
```

here is the problem that this code is not acceptable in the description tag

Comment: What do you mean by "not acceptable"? Not acceptable by who?

Comment: i write this in Eclipse, when writing php inside this codes it doesn't render it as php but like an simple text, also when testing this page in browser it parse every thing without the description

Comment: So this doesn't work when you test it on a live server with PHP enabled? That would be very strange, I don't think the PHP parser listens to CDATA tags. Hmmmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC character_limiter() doesn't echo results, just returns them. So:

1) make sure you've loaded the text helper in your controller before calling that function
 2) try with:

```
<description><?php echo htmlspecialchars(character_limiter($entry->text_nw, 200)); ?></description>
```

Comment: Thank you Pekka, Damien Pirsy
the problem that i wasn't write the echo before character_limiter. now everything is going well thank you